# How to use REGEXTRACT to extract certain characters between two strings

Tags: regex, google-sheets, regex-negation

I am trying to extract a person's name between different characters. For example, the cells contains this information

```
PATIENT: 2029985 - COLLINS, JUNIOR .
PATIENT: 1235231-02 - JERRY JR, PATRICK .
PATIENT: 986435--EXP-- - JULIUS, DANIEL .
PATIENT: 2021118-02 - DRED-HARRY, KEVIN .
```

My goal is to use one REGEXTRACT formula to get the following:

```
COLLINS, JUNIOR
JERRY JR, PATRICK
JULIUS, DANIEL
LOVE ALSTON, BRENDA
```

So far, I have come up with the formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(B3:B, "-(.*)\."))
```

Where B3 contains the first information

Using that formula, I get:

```
COLLINS, JUNIOR
02 - JERRY JR, PATRICK
02 - LOVE-ALSTON, BRENDA 
-EXP-- - JULIUS, DANIEL
02 - DRED-HARRY, KEVIN
```

I managed to get the first name down but how do I go about extracting the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(B3:B, "\s-\s+([^.]*?)\s*\."))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OpljW6/3). *Details*:

- `\s-\s+` - a whitespace, `-`, one or more whitespaces
- `([^.]*?)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than a `.` as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\.` - a `.` char.

Comment: That works! I have another question though. What if in another cell, the information has a period without a space between the period in the end. For example, PATIENT: 2021118-02 - DRED-HARRY, JASON. (This time, there is no space in between the period). Which formula would work that would both satisfy the condition of having a space and no space between a period at the end?

Comment: @KielPagtama change `\s+` with `\s*`

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked beautifully! Is it okay if you explain in detail why the formula works? Like why each variable in the formula does the way it does and how the them working together produces the results?

Comment: @KielPagtama I have explained the pattern, what is exactly not clear? Note the capturing group, Group 1, is the actual result of `REGEXEXTRACT`, as it returns only the captured substring if there is a capturing group in the pattern.

Comment: Can I use two groups in the formula if I wanted to extract the numbers too?

Comment: @KielPagtama Yes, but then the result will span on two columns.

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following regex.

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/nNmyo2/2)

```
^PATIENT:.*-\s+([^.]*?)\s*\.
```

***OR*** try following Google-sheet forumla:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(B3:B, "^PATIENT:.*-\s+([^.]*?)\s*\."))
```

***Explanation:*** Checking if line/value starts from PATIENT followed by `:` till `-`(using greedy mechanism here), which is followed by spaces(1 or more occurrences). Then creating one and only capturing group which contains everything just before `.`(dot) in it making it non-greedy, closing capturing group which is followed by spaces(0 or more occurrences) followed by a literal dot.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using lazy match approach in regex, please try following regex.

```
.*?\s-\s([^.]*?)\s*\.
```

Google-sheet formula will be as follows:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(B3:B, ".*?\s-\s([^.]*?)\s*\."))
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/jquCnS/1)